# LDAP query returns more results with a longer wildcard

Tags: active-directory, ldap

How does the LDAP wildcard search work? I seem to be seriously missing something.

I have one query similar to

```
(|(cn=john*)(sn=john*)(givenName=john*))
```

which returns 30 results and one similar to

```
(|(cn=johns*)(sn=johns*)(givenName=johns*))
```

that returns 162 results. The only difference on the input is that the second has *more* letters before the wildcard.

Both queries succeed with no errors, and the smaller number of results is a subset of the larger number; the only difference on the output side is that the second query returns more results.

Comment: Are you 100% sure about this? Should be the other way around, of course. Are the 30 results a proper subset of the 162?

Comment: do you have substring indexes on all of those attributes?

Comment: EJP, yep, And I have no theories left about what's happening. The 30 results *are* a proper subset. Dave, I don't know about the indexes; we're trying to check now. (Yay, different organizations.)

Answer (score 0):

Does your query finishes completely or returns X results and then some kind of error?

I can imagine a situation where the index for a shorter value "john*" is not maintained because the "john" is too common and it exceeds the limit for the index. In such case LDAP server could fall back to traversing all entries in the directory before reaching another limit - the one for how many entries might be traversed on the server-side. Unfortunately there were only that many matching entries found and returned. BUT... there should be some kind of error/warning/exception at the end if this is the case.

With the longer value "johns*", the index might be in place as there are less entries for such value, so the server can rely on it to return the complete result set.

Comment: I've updated the question, but the queries do finish and don't return errors. Unfortunately, I don't have any information about the indexing or the configuration of the Active Directory servers.